# Bluetooth microphones not working (speakers do work) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headset, bluetooth-speaker, a2dp

I've bought a bluetooth headset *"Samnyte K10"* and connected it to my computer via bluetooth. It plays sounds but my laptop doesn't receive sound from the microphone.
In the *Settings* -> *Sound* configuration window, there were bars shown in pale orange for the input volume that, however, didn't move. Furthermore, I couldn't set the headset as sound input permanently, it would always switch back to *"Internal Microphone"*. To address this problem, I've changed the last line of the `default.pa` file in `/etc/pulse/` to set the bluetooth microphone as default audio input:

```
set-default-source bluez_source00_0B_00_D6_F3.headset_head_unit
```

Now the bars in the sound configuration window are just white. I still cannot record audio though...
The device ist listed in the volume control as headset.

Does anyone have a clue where the problem might be and how to solve it?

Update: I tried another bluetooth headset, both play sound only in A2DP Profile, if I set them as microphone, they change to HSP/HFP and won't work at all.

Comment: It somehow seems to be related with my built-in bluetooth chip, since it works now when I
1st: Use an external USB bluetooth stick and
2nd: Pair only when the device is in pairing mode, even if it can also be found under known devices when it is available but not pairing